# Choose correct file with ansible depending on server type

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to deploy my configuration to different servers. Configuration consists of different files and also a keystore which holds certificates for communication.

I want to be able to deploy the exact same configuration to different servers, but dev, staging and prod servers have different certificates.

My current idea is to use hosts file to define server type, something like this:

```
all:
  hosts:

    prod_server_1:
      ansible_user: apps
      ansible_ssh_host: 192.168.0.1
      type: prod
      
    staging_server_1:
      ansible_user: apps
      ansible_ssh_host: 192.168.0.2
      type: staging
```

And then add all three keystores to configuration (prod.ks, staging.ks and dev.ks), but only copy the one that matches the server type I am deploying to. Something like:

```
- copy:
    src: /conf/keystores/{{type}}.ks
    dest: /conf/keystore.ks
```

Is this kind of solution suggested or is there a more standard way of solving this kind of cases?

Comment: It should work exactly as you've written it. Can you try it out?

Comment: Programmatically it works, but my question was aimed to find out if this is also a reasonable approach to the problem, or are similar problems solved some other way with ansible? :)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### To actually answer your question.

To me, it seems that this is a reasonable way to do this kind of task. Since, the keystores are binary files you cannot do much within the file itself and it is necessary to store 3 different files. But, I would suggest one change to the inventory file. When you have a small number of hosts, like in your example, it is easy to set the `type` variable for each host. Now, let's say you have a 100 hosts. It would be very difficult to keep track of each host and set the variable for each host. So, it is better to have host groups for each different type of host and assign a group variable for each group. This way you can add and remove machines from the group without having to keep track of the `type` variable. Look at the example below to see how this new inventory would look like.

Additional info: If the file were a text config file, with config specific to each host, you could write a jinja template inside the file and then use the `template` module for ansible to evaluate the template and copy it to the server. The advantage in this case would be that there would be only 1 task (as you have now), and only 1 template file to manage changes. As opposed to having a separate file for every different type of host.

### Example:

The inventory file `test-inv.yml`:

```yaml
---
  prod_servers:
    hosts:
      prod_server_1:
        ansible_user: root
        ansible_ssh_host: some-prod-host-1
      prod_server_2:
        ansible_user: root
        ansible_ssh_host: some-prod-host-2
    vars:
      type: prod

  staging_servers:
    hosts:
      stage_server_1:
        ansible_user: root
        ansible_ssh_host: some-stage-host-3
      stage_server_2:
        ansible_user: root
        ansible_ssh_host: some-stage-host-4
    vars:
      type: staging
...
```

Then I wrote this small playbook `test.yml`:

```yaml
---

- name: test variables...
  hosts: all

  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="type={{type}}"
```

And this was the output:

```
$ ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook -i test-inv.yml test.yml

PLAY [test variables...] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [prod_server_2] => 
  msg: type=prod
ok: [prod_server_1] => 
  msg: type=prod
ok: [stage_server_1] => 
  msg: type=staging
ok: [stage_server_2] => 
  msg: type=staging

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
prod_server_1              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
prod_server_2              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
stage_server_1             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
stage_server_2             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Programmatically it works, but my question was aimed to find out if this is also a reasonable approach to the problem, or are similar problems solved some other way with ansible? :)

Comment: Ah my bad. I see what you’re saying now. From my limited work on ansible, this seems like a reasonable solution for this kind of problem, as long as you have a well-defined inventory.